# make error "virtual memory exhausted stop " while building spidermonkey

Tags: makefile, configure, building

I got this error while I was building spidermonkey using cygwin terminal, the error is

```
 "***virtual memory exhausted stop"
```

so how to solve this error ?

Comment: This means make ran out of memory.  Either your makefile has a bug where it's infinitely recursing and eventually eating up all memory, or your system doesn't have enough memory to perform that build.  You could try shutting down other programs on the system.  That's about all we can suggest, with the information provided.

Comment: this problem appeared after solving another problem in make which is "" make error : *** target pattern contains no %"" and I updated my cygwin with the required package, but after installing and trying to build again the virtual memory error appeared, is this mean they are related ? or what?
and how to know that makefile has a bug ?
and while I was searching on google I hit with some solution that it is due to a bug in cygwin make.exe itself, and I should bind mingw windows make.exe to cygwin and I don't know how to do this ?!

Comment: We can't really help with this level of detail.  I suggest that you edit your question and make clear what OS and OS version you're using, what cygwin version you're using, what spidermonkey version you're using, what steps you took to get to this point.  You should also modify the tags on your question to include (at least) cygwin, and something about spidermonkey if you can find one.  Remove the "configure" and "building" tags as those are not useful.  And finally you might have better luck asking on a cygwin or spidermonkey  mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Or, simply add a swap file to increase memory, hope that helps

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Answer (score 0):

As a potential quick fix: You can reduce the memory usage by doing

```
make -j 1
```

which tells the build tool to use only one CPU.