# How much memory is typically needed to build octave?

Tags: octave

I'm trying to build octave on a RHEL8.1 VM with 16GB of RAM, and it almost immediately dies with the following message:

```
% make clean
preserving existing HG-ID file
make: *** virtual memory exhausted.  Stop.
```

I know very little about octave at this point, but I'm surprised it would take more than 16GB to build it.

It did build successfully on a bare-metal RHEL8.1 host with much more memory.

Are there any known issues likely to be at play here?

If not, how much memory should I generally expect to need to build octave?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make error "virtual memory exhausted stop " while building spidermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286653/make-error-virtual-memory-exhausted-stop-while-building-spidermonkey)

Answer (score 0):

I have built on a baremetal 4 Gb without issues. (Actually a 2Gb before, but I have tried a recent build with it). Its a little slow to compile.

I also have used a 8 Gb ubuntu virtual machine successfully.

You may be spawning several make jobs during the build, each which uses memory, so you could control that by specifying number of jobs to run to 1.

make -j 1